# simplexml_load_string failure when using heredoc-style string parameter

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, heredoc

I am trying one simple PHP XML example as following.

```
// code of PHP
===================================================
<?php
  $string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>George</to>
<from>John</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget the meeting!</body>
</note>
XML;

  print "BEGIN</br>"; 
  print "String:</br>{$string}";

  $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
  print "</br>XML Obj:</br>";
  print_r($xml);
  print "</br>Var Dump:</br>";  
  var_dump($xml);
  print "</br>END"; 
?>
===================================================
```

and the outputs seems OK

```
// output
===================================================
BEGIN
String:
George John Reminder Don't forget the meeting!
XML Obj:
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [to] => George [from] => John [heading] => Reminder [body] => Don't forget the meeting! )
Var Dump:
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (4) { ["to"]=> string(6) "George" ["from"]=> string(4) "John" ["heading"]=> string(8) "Reminder" ["body"]=> string(25) "Don't forget the meeting!" }
END
===================================================
```

While when I try to format the first line of heredoc-style string by adding some blanks ahead of it, adding two blanks before following line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`，then it always failed to output $xml Object info .

```
// code of PHP
===================================================
<?php
  $string = <<<XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>George</to>
<from>John</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget the meeting!</body>
</note>
XML;
... ...
===================================================

// output
===================================================
BEGIN
String:
George John Reminder Don't forget the meeting!
XML Obj:

Var Dump:
bool(false)
END
```

Hope someone can help me!!!
Thanks very much.

Comment: Don't put blanks before the prologue? Why do you _want_ to do that?

Comment: +1, or use $xml = simplexml_load_string(trim($string));

Comment: Thanks for your help, because it is a little ugly, so i just try to format it, well, it seems there are some guidelines to end label of heredoc style string, while i did not find any requirement to the string content, and after format the string content, it always failed, and after several tries, i find only blank before the first line of the string content affect the result, and i am curious, so i post the question.

Comment: Hi,
In this case, I know this failure is caused by those blanks before the <?xml ... ?>, which is a invalid XML (after checking XML spec), while anyone who can share any experience on debugging those failures, I even do not know where and how to start the debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no valid XML. Have a look at the [XML specs for documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#sec-well-formed):

```
document    ::=     prolog element Misc*
prolog      ::=     XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?
XMLDecl     ::=     '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
```

`document` decribes what other grammar tokens XML documents are build from, starting with a `prolog`. This *may* contain an `XMLDecl`, which again starts with `<?xml`. In short: there is no whitespace allowed before the declaration, if there is one.

---

If you are under control of the XML (which you seem to be): Just don't do that, I'd regard this to be malicious as everybody having to deal with the code after you will wonder what's going on.

If you cannot change the input, because somebody else is sending broken XML files:

- tell him to ship well-formed XML or
- "preprocess" the non-XML with `trim($string)` like already proposed in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jens Erat, I will further detail check the XML Spec